# PHP regex and preg_replace issue

Tags: php, regex

I was looking through someone else's old code and having some trouble understanding it.

He has:

```
explode(' ', strtolower(preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]+/i', ' ', preg_replace('/\&#?[a-z0-9]{2,4}\;/', ' ', preg_replace('/<[^>]+>/', ' ', $texts)))));
```

I think the first regex exclude the `a-z` and `0-9`, I am not sure what the second regex does though. The third one matches anything inside the `'< >'` except `'>'`

The result will output an array with every word in the `$texts` variable, however, I just don't know how the codes produce this. I do understand what `preg_replace` and other functions do , just don't know how the process works

Comment: That many nested preg_replace calls is just going to lead to confusion

Comment: Break it up into three separate statements, using temporary variables. Then it gets easier to follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `/[^a-z0-9-]+/i` will match (and subsequently replace with empty space) any character *except* a-z and 0-9.  The `^` in [`^...]` means to *negate* the character set contained therein.

- `[^a-z0-9]` matches any *non* alphanumeric character
- `+` means one or more of the preceding
- `/i` makes it match case-insensitively

The expression `/\&#?[a-z0-9]{2,4}\;/` matches a `&` followed optionally by `#`, followed by two to four letters and numbers, ending with a `;` This would [match HTML entities like](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html) `&nbsp;` or `&#39;`

- `&#?` matches either `&` or `&#` since `?` makes the preceding `#` optional The `&` doesn't actually need escaping.
- `[a-z0-9]{2,4}` matches between two and four alphanumeric characters
- `;` is the literal semicolon. It doesn't actually need escaping.

Partly as you suspected, the last one will replace any tags like `<tagname>` or `<tagname attr='value'>` or `</tagname>` with an empty space. Note that it matches the *whole* tag, not just the inner contents of `<>`.

- `<` is the literal character
- `[^>]+` is every character up to but not including the next `>`
- `>` is the literal character

I would really recommend rewriting this as three separate calls to `preg_replace()` rather than nesting them.

```
// Strips tags.  
// Would be better done with strip_tags()!!
$texts = preg_replace('/<[^>]+>/', ' ', $texts);
// Removes HTML entities
$texts = preg_replace('/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,4};/', ' ', $texts);
// Removes remainin non-alphanumerics
$texts = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]+/i', ' ', $texts);
$array = explode(' ', $texts);
```

Comment: ...matches a `&` optionally followed by `#`?

Answer (score 2):

This code looks like it...

1. strips HTML/XML tags (anything between < and >)
2. then anything that starts with & or &# and is 2-4 characters long (alpha numeric)
3. then strips anything that is not an alphanumeric or a dash

*In processing order of nesting*

```
/<[^>]+>/

Match the character “<” literally «<»
Match any character that is NOT a “>” «[^>]+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character “>” literally «>»


/\&#?[a-z0-9]{2,4}\;/

Match the character “&” literally «\&»
Match the character “#” literally «#?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
Match a single character present in the list below «[a-z0-9]{2,4}»
   Between 2 and 4 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{2,4}»
   A character in the range between “a” and “z” «a-z»
   A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
Match the character “;” literally «\;»


/[^a-z0-9-]+/i

Options: case insensitive

Match a single character NOT present in the list below «[^a-z0-9-]+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   A character in the range between “a” and “z” «a-z»
   A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
   The character “-” «-»
```